# Text entry box on quickly not working

Tags: application-development, quickly

right now I'm doing the '[create your first ubuntu app](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sO8hiPreNBg)' youtube tutorial. I'm trying the text entry box and nothing comes up when I enter text. Here's my code,

```
self.urlentry = self.builder.get_object("urlentry")
def on_urlentry_activate(self, widget):
        print "woo!"
```

when I press enter, or any other button, it does not display 'woo' on the terminal/Command line.

Comment: Not having any experience with quickly, I think you need to somehow attach the event handler (on_urlentry_activate) to the control (self.urlentry)

Comment: Could you explain that a little more. I tried attaching it and the command line said syntax error.

Comment: Actually, I was wrong - I watched the video and it seems that in Quickly those event handlers are found "automagically", no need to bind them explicitly. It would be helpful if you provided more code.

Comment: Alright here is my code. It's exactly the same as his.

Comment: Have you connected urlentry to on_urlentry_activate using glade?

Comment: self.refreshbutton = self.builder.get_object("refreshbutton")
        self.urlentry = self.builder.get_object("urlentry")

    def on_refreshbutton_clicked(self, widget):
        
        print "refresh"

    def on_self.urlentry_activate(self, widget):
        
        print "Hello"

Comment: yes you're supposed to instatiate self.urlentry = self.builder.get_object("urlentry") then declare def on_urlentry_activate(self, widget): print "Woo". and it's supposed to print "woo"! everytime I press enter. I'm using 12.1, just in case there is a bug.

Comment: How do you connect urlentry to on_urlentry_activate using glade?

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem where I couldn't type in the text entry field as well as the function not working as mentioned above.

My fix was under the common tab for the text entry widget, `"can focus" = Yes`

I can now enter text and the function runs.